# MongoDB : Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, osx-mavericks, database

My problem is similar to other inputs and suggestions on this site, but none has helped me. After installing MongoDB, has not started because the database is not running.

First try to run mongo and I answered this:

```
Mac-Pro-de-User: ~ user $ mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4 
connecting to: test 
2014-10-28T10: 47: 08713-0700 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno: 61 Connection refused 
2014-10-28T10: 47: 08713-0700 Error: could not connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) Attempt connection failed at src / mongo / shell / mongo.js: 146 
exception: connect failed
```

Then try to check the mongod and I answered this:

```
Mac-Pro-de-User: ~ user $ mongod 
mongod --help for help and startup options 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting: pid = 926 port = 27017 dbpath = / data / db host = 64-bit Mac-Pro-de-Ernesto.local 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, Should be at Least 1000 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] Build info: Darwin bs-osx108-4 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root: xnu-2050.48.12 ~ 1 / x86_64 RELEASE_X86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION = 1_49 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] allocator: system 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34485-0700 [initandlisten] options: {} 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34486-0700 [initandlisten] journal dir = / data / db / journal 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34486-0700 [initandlisten] recover: no journal files present, no recovery needed 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34500-0700 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.ns, filling zeroes With ... 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34500-0700 [FileAllocator] creating directory / data / db / _tmp 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34512-0700 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.ns, size: 16MB, took 0.011 secs 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 34726-0700 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling zeroes With ... 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 35398-0700 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB, took 0.671 secs 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 35695-0700 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: {v: 1, key: {_id: 1}, name: "_id_" ns "local.startup_log"} 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 35695-0700 [initandlisten] index added to empty collection 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 35695-0700 [initandlisten] Local command $ cmd command. Create {create: "startup_log" size: 10485760, capped: true} ntoreturn: 1 KeyUpdates: 0 numYields: 0 reslen: 37 1194ms 
2014-10-28T10: 59: 35695-0700 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017 
2014-10-28T11: 00: 34516-0700 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res: 33 virt: 2653 
2014-10-28T11: 00: 34516-0700 [clientcursormon] mapped (incl journal view): 160 
2014-10-28T11: 00: 34516-0700 [clientcursormon] connections: 0
```

Then try again to connect and spend some time, and again says the same:

```
2014-10-28T11: 05: 34589-0700 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res: 33 virt: 2653 
2014-10-28T11: 05: 34589-0700 [clientcursormon] mapped (incl journal view): 160 
2014-10-28T11: 05: 34589-0700 [clientcursormon] connections: 0
```

And so on. If you can help would greatly appreciate it.

> PS: There is already the / data / db with 777 permissions, and I'm
>   using OSX Mavericks 10.9.5

Comment: Just putting it out there - I simply turned my computer on and off and it started working again. This has happened to me twice

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you running all of these commands in the same terminal as separate actions as your timestamps suggest? (if not, I would expect to see overlap between the failures and logs in order to diagnose properly).

If so, then what you are doing is as follows:

1. Starting a shell, attempting to connect to a non-running database (connection refused)
2. Starting the database, seeing 0 connections in the logs
3. Stopping the database (Ctrl-C or similar), starting a shell, fails to connect again because database has been shut down
4. Starting the database, seeing 0 connections in logs
5. repeat

The database needs to be running concurrently with the shell so you can connect to it.  Hence you should start the `mongod` process in one terminal, leave it running, and then open a new terminal (or tab) and run the `mongo` command to connect to the still running database.  The other option is to [run `mongod` as a daemon](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon), which will allow you to run the `mongo` command in the same terminal once it returns.

Note: you should never have a folder with 777 permissions, it is not required and is a significant security risk.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Run mongod in the background and can be accessed from mongo sell. Can you tell me what kind of permissions you recommend for this folder. Thanks again =)

Comment: Assuming it is owned by you and you are running mongod as yourself (not using sudo), then 755 would be fine, you just don't want it world writable.  If it is not owned by you then chown it first (`chown -R user:staff /data/db` - replace user with your actual username).

Comment: Thank you very much =) was very helpful = D

Comment: Thank you of all of the answers on the web, this one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this command.

sudo chown mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

And

sudo service mongod restart

Comment: Thank you, this helped me with the issue that I was having reg connection to the local mongodb server

Answer (score 1):

> Fixed!

The reason was the dbpath variable in /etc/mongodb.conf. Previously, I was using mongodb 1.8, where the default value for dbpath was /data/db. The upstart job mongodb(which comes with mongodb-10gen package) invokes the mongod with --config /etc/mongodb.conf option.

As a solution, I only had to change the owner of the /data/db directory recursively.

Like this: **Go to** "/data" **location in the terminal** and then type

`sudo chown -R <username>:foldername`

*For example:*

`sudo chown -R raja db/`

Answer (score 1):

Hello just check  if you created the /data/db path and if you did then give 755 permission with chmod.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is already an accepted answer to this questions which the author confirmed was working. Please avoid adding answers unless they provide something new. In addition running with 777 can be a security issue and should be avoided.